# Can we store records got from a query to a list in stored procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedure, I am using hibernate concept to retrieve data from the database. client server traffic is more so I decide to move to SP by doing simple logics in server side and return needed values to front end. Now I want to know that is there any way to store records to list, so that I can rotate the list of records in a loop and ask them to come one by one and get a single field from a record and make a process then return a value to front end like we are doing in Java? List,getter,setter and generic class to store needed entities. I am confused with this.Please advise and guide me to know well about stored procedures.

Comment: If you use a `Query.scroll()` then the database should do this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to use a `cursor` over your query results, generate a `temporary table`, and then `select` the contents of that temporary table to return from your stored procedure.

You should be able to find plenty of examples online for `cursor`s and `temporary table`s.